# If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous surjection, must it be open?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous surjection, must it be open?

I think not. I proved if $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an open continuous surjection, then $f$ is a homeomorphism. So, if the question is true, every continuous surjection must be a homeomorphism. But, I didn't find a counterexample. Can someone help me?

Comment: What about a continuous surjections that is constant on an interval? for example,$f(x)=x$ for $x\le 0$, $f(x)=0$ for $0<x<1$ and $f(x)=x-1$ for $x\ge 1$.

Comment: This is very helpful! Thanks!

Comment: If you want one with a closed formula, you can take $f(x)=x^3-x$. Plotting this should make the properties clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any surjection that attains a local extremum suffices. Consider for instance
$$
f(x) = x(x-1)(x-2) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x
$$
Note that $f$ is not an open map, since the interval $(0,1)$ is mapped to an interval of the form $(0,a]$, which is not open.

Comment: Looks like SmileyCraft had the same idea